# Laravel using WebSocket Configuration

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-websockets

I have a Laravel application with WebSocket functionality using the laravel-websockets package. The WebSocket setup works perfectly in my local environment, but when I deploy it to my live server, the WebSocket connections fail. The server returns a WebSocket connection failed error in the browser console.

I've ensured that my WebSocket server is up and running on the live server, and I've checked the server logs for any issues. Both my local and live server environments have the same version of Laravel and PHP. The WebSocket URLs and configurations are also correct in my JavaScript code.
@php version 8.1
@laravel version 9
What could be causing this discrepancy between the local and live environments? Are there any server-specific factors that I should consider when debugging WebSocket issues on a live server? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You application is running behind a reverse proxy?